# day of the week issue always prompts monday no matter the entry

Tags: dayofweek

The outcome of this is when you enter any number 1-7 you will get the day of that number. for some reason it will always prompt Monday. How can I fix this?

```
 '#Enter a number range 1-7 for the day of the week Example 1=Monday
#variables to represent the days of the week
num = float(input ("Enter the number for the day of week"))
Monday_number = 1
Tuesday_number = 2
Wednesday_number = 3
Thursday_number = 4
Friday_number = 5
Saturday_number = 6
Sunday_number = 7
Other_number = 8

#the day of the week
if Monday_number == 1:
print('Monday')
elif Tuesday_number == 2:
print('Tuesday')
elif Wednesday_number == 3:
print('Wednesday')
elif Thursday_number == 4:
print('Thursday')
elif Friday_number == 5:
print('Friday')
elif Saturday_number == 6:
print('Saturday')
elif Sunday_number == 7:
print('Sunday')
else:
if Other_number > 7:
    print('Invalid number entered')'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not comparing `num`, the user input, to anything. In your if statements, you should be sequentially comparing `num` to each of the day of week constants. Better yet, you could be using a lookup table:

```
days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
user_input = input('Enter the day of the week: ')
print(days[int(user_input)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Step through your algorithm mentally, line-by-line.  What happens when you get to the first `if` statement?